# Ways to sort k balls into n boxes in descending order? So each box has less than the one before

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Is there some equation or formula that would let me know how many ways there are to sort k balls into n boxes so that each box has less than the previous box? And that no box is empty.

For example, for 2 boxes and 3 balls there is only one [2,1],
For 3 boxes and 8 balls there are 2 [5,2,1] and [4,3,1]

If there isn't a formula then what area of math would this be under? How could I find the solution?

Comment: Your examples seem to include a condition that no box is empty.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Yes that is what I want, sorry I should have put that in

Comment: I think you might be dealing with "partitions of $k$ into $n$ distinct parts".

Answer (score 1):

You want $q(k,n)$, the number of partitions of $k$ into $n$ distinct parts; its array is [OEIS A008289](http://oeis.org/A008289). There is no nice closed form, but for fixed $n$ the generating function is

$$Q_n(x)=\sum_{k\ge 0}q(k,n)x^k=\frac{x^{n+\binom{n}2}}{(1-x)\ldots(1-x^n)}\,;$$

see, for instance, Part $4$ of [this PDF](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emhaiman/math172-spring10/partitions.pdf), with an argument that also shows that $$q(k,n)=p\left(k-\binom{n}2,n\right)\,,$$

where $p(m,\ell)$ is the number of partitions of $m$ into exactly $\ell$ unrestricted parts. There is no nice formula for either of these functions, but $p(m,\ell)$ does satisfy the following recurrence:

$$p(m,\ell)=p(m-1,\ell-1)+p(n-\ell,\ell)$$

with initial conditions $p(m,\ell)=0$ for $\ell>m$, $p(m,m)=1$, and $p(m,0)=0$. Wolfram has more information on both [the function $q$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html) and [the function $p$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html), as well as references.

Comment: Thanks a ton this is super usefull!

Comment: @JamesHowe: You’re welcome; glad it helped!